# How to get a element name in html for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

What I need to do is get the an element property name and make a post, the post part, I think I can handle, but I'm couldn't do it.

I have a list of items with a loop of CompanyNames:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
@{
    foreach (var item in List)
    {
        <a class="dropdown-item" name="@item.CompanyToken" id="selector">
            <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400" id="CompanyId"></i>
            @item.CompanyName
        </a>
    }
}
</div>
```

and in the JavaScript code I was trying to get the `item,CompanyToken` by the id selector, but o success :

```
<script>
    $("#selector").click(function () {
        var val = $("selector").attr("name").val();
      alert( val);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use `var val = $("selector").attr("name");` only

Comment: `var val = $("selector").attr("name").val();` here you selector is not correct if its `ID`, you should have used `#selector`, you did it in first line and then under click handle you haven't used `#`

Comment: but in `for each` loop you are using the same id `selector` mean multiple `a` can have same id value, thats not correct. if you want to catch click event for all `a`, then may be use the `class` and then use the `class` selector for click event.

Comment: @DeepakSharma do you have any example ?

Comment: @NathielPaulino check the fiddle, here I added 3 `a` and bound jQuery click event.  https://jsfiddle.net/b2yao0r3/

Answer (score 0):

Each element should have its unique ID therefore use class in loops:

```
foreach (var item in List)
     {
       <a class="dropdown-item" name="@item.CompanyToken" class="selector">
       <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400" id="CompanyId"></i>
      @item.CompanyName
      </a>
     }
```

If you want to get attribute value from ID of element:

```
var val = $("#selector").attr("name");
console.log(val);
```

[Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_get.asp)

Comment: you used the `class` on element and using the id selector in jquery, it will not work. use the `.selector` in jquery. `#` is used for id, and `.` is used for class.

Comment: That's why I added link in answer. I am telling about use class in loop & access elements using `$("").get(n)` or `$("")`